# ASUS PU301LA Ubuntu Installation: NMI: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s!

Tags: system-installation

Ok so I'm trying to install ubuntu onto my laptop that I've just received. The error in the title occurs as soon as I click install ubuntu. Once or twice its let me get further than for example it allowed me to 'Try ubuntu without installing' once and its also gone through the full installation once however on booting on installing the error in the title occurs and there is no clear reason as to why that is on various posts with the same issues (on other websites).

Some people have stated that it has something to do with the power supply and others are stating that its fixed by updating the kernal however I cannot update the kernel without actually managing to load linux and of course its a laptop so changing the power supply is out of the question.

Does anybody have a clear fix as to why it won't install?

[image: Image of Stack]

Comment: Its a duplicate however the answer in this post is the same as the accepted answer in the other post and did not work hence not being accepted as the answer here.

Comment: The answer that is posted here by ArgAthens is specific for computers that have an Nvidia GPU.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem trying to install a new Dell.  For me adding the nouveau.modeset=0 option to the kernel fixed it.  Looking into the power supply and kernel versions ended up being a red herring.